# Docker with `/bin/bash -c` running mysql deamon

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, docker

I'm trying the `mysql` container. The `CMD` parameter for that container is `mysqld`. Therefore, the following parameters are the same.

```
docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=proot --rm mysql
docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=proot --rm mysql mysqld
```

Now the problem arrives when I want to use multiple commands. In order to use multiple commands in a docker container you have to use `/bin/bash -c`. I exemplify by using only the `mysqld` command:

```
docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=proot --rm mysql /bin/bash -c "mysqld"
```

This command throws me the following error.

```
mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
```

And then mysql deamon stops and I don't understand the reason.

I want to use the `/bin/bash -c` syntax because I want to use multiple commands like first starting the deamon and then something else `mysqld & some other command`. I don't want to create another container as a workaround for this problem.

Sidenote: I'm using `--rm` because I'm troubleshooting, otherwise I'll use `-d` to detach the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer from the github community](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/202). They said ***the entyrypoint script only does the*** `initdb` ***if*** `mysqld` ***is the argument***. Thus said, the workaround is to use `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` to put any `.sh` or `.sql` files, then the files run once `mysql` is already running.

Therefore, the final answer is adding the directory `-v /local/dir:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` with the scripts to initialize. As an example:

```
docker run --name db -v $(pwd):/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=proot --rm mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

While the `CMD` for the mysql Docker image is `mysqld` it also has `ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]` which may not work with your bash command.

Running another process would somewhat defeat the point of using this image, which other than not being best practice for a Docker container, make it less immutable and harder to debug, so I wouldn't really call using another container a "workaround" -- what you are trying do is more the workaround.

So you might need to override the `ENTRYPOINT` or create a custom Dockerfile.